# Acrobat (reader): to open at a specific page number via command line on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, acrobat

I am running a Windows batch file to convert a document to `PDF`and on the last line of the batch file I have:

`Acrobat "%1.pdf"`

This opens the produced `PDF`file just fine but I also wish to be able to open the `PDF`file at some specific page of the document.

So how to extend the command that I am using above to force the `PDF`file to open at a desired page number?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the command line switch /A:

```
Acrobat /A "page=<pagenum>" %1.pdf
```

Replace  with whatever page you like to be displayed. For additional open parameters, please refer to Adobe's partner documentation:

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf

Good luck!

Living

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Acrobat /A "page=3" "%1.pdf"
```

AFAIK the above works in Acrobat 7 and up (maybe even earlier version but not sure).

Comment: @ Yahia Thanks. Your answer is equally good but @Living has provided some additional useful information. 1 vote up.