# Open PDF to a specific page

Tags: java, pdf

Is there a way to go to open a **specific** PDF-page with Java?

It can either open the page in Adobe Reader or a built in reader in Java.
I have the file path and the file saved locally.

Comment: This doesn't work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546968/open-pdf-file-on-fly-from-java-application

Comment: RickS Is exactly what i answered.... it must work.

Comment: The provided link doesn't explain how to open a specific page, but just the PDF as a whole.

Comment: You want to open the PDF and have it automatically go to a certain page?

Comment: I guess you would need something more complex....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554478/acrobat-reader-to-open-at-a-specific-page-number-via-command-line-on-windows It's a little bit old, but maybe it still works.

Comment: Mastov, this could work. Do someone know know how I can do start Adobe with parameters on Mac? I know how on Windows, but don't got one close by.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a couple of options here.

The easiest way to do this on Windows would be using the command line. Both Acrobat and Reader take command line arguments such as zoom level and starting page. The command to open a document on a specific page on Windows looks like this:

Acrobat.exe /A "page=1000" "C:\example.pdf"

And here is a reference of all the parameters Acrobat and Reader take on Windows - [Parameters for Opening PDF Files](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf).

On Mac, things get a bit tricky. Neither Acrobat nor Reader take command line parameters there. However, you still have some options on the Mac. Your best option would be to use AppleScript. Acrobat has extensive support for it, it's fairly easy to get started, and you can even import the AcrobatLibrary and see a list of available API. [Here is a good article](http://xprepress.com/dealing-acrobat-applescript/) to get you started on this. As with Windows, it looks like this is both available for Acrobat and Reader.

I've put together a small script that should open a document and then go to a specific page.

```
tell application "Adobe Acrobat Pro"
    tell PDF Window 1
        goto page 3
    end tell
end tell
```

[Here is a good way](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-run-execute-applescript-java-mac) to open the newly created AppleScript from Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "go-to" PDF action to the document's "open" viewer application event. Here is how you do it with our company product PDFOne (for Java). You might be able to do the same with other PDF libraries.
http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=217&t=Trouble_free_Linking_To_PDF_Pages_Online

Sample PDF: http://www.gnostice.com/newsletters/downloads/2011_03/PDF_that_skips_to_page_3_by_default.pdf

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you are asking for...
Say you have a document that has several pages of minutia at the beginning (perhaps a bunch of legalese that you’re not going to read the first time, much less every time).  Rather than scrolling past all that minutia every time, you want it to go straight to the table of contents so you can find what you’re looking for more quickly.

If that sounds similar to what you are wanting, then here you go…
(By the way, I’m using Adobe Acrobat Pro.  I don’t know if this will work for Reader.)

Open the document in Adobe.
Click Enable All Features.
Click File.
Click Properties.
Click on the tab called Initial View.
Find where it says “Open to page” and enter the page number you want it to open to.
Click OK.
Save the file.
Close the file.
Reopen the file.  (It should open to the page you set.)